# iOS UI Tests Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, mach

I'm trying to run some UI tests for my iOS app. I was successfully able to record my UI tests, but when running them, I get a linker error:
[image]

I have a UI Testing Target added to my project, and my UI Test file has been added to that target.

I've already been able to write and run several Unit Tests without a problem.

Anyone know where I should look to solve this, or have a guess what the problem may be?

EDIT: The full log output shows that the UI test file can't import an SDK that my target app relies on.

Comment: what does your import look like?

Comment: Hey @SeanLintern88, I'm importing XCTest at the top of my UI Test File. Thanks!

Comment: I mean are you importing anything other than XCTest/@testable APp

Comment: @SeanLintern88 Nope, just importing XCTest

Comment: It should be possible to right-click on the “Linker command failed...” text. This should show a menu with the option “Reveal in Log”. Clicking on that option should show a more detailed error message. Can you try and possibly add the error message to your question?

Comment: @Mats Updated the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, when I created my UITest target, a linker flag was added in the target that shouldn't have been there (`-lMySDK`).

Removing that flag resolved the linker error.